# AWS RDS unreachable for a short period of time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

we are using Amazon RDS to run our Prestashop websites.

This night, we went through two hours of downtime on one of our site (yes, it hurts..), and I am now trying to identify the problem:

First of all, I looked at the website logs. I found the following error that triggered more than a thousand times during the downtime period:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host '********.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com'
```

I need to insist on the fact that **their was no human action** to end this downtime and that the problem was solved "by himself".

Another clue is that my "maintenance window" is set to Thursday between 1AM and 1:30 AM, and that this maintenance window corresponds approximately with the beginning of the downtime period.

However, I can't see any operation of that type in my "journal", so I really don't know where should I look to check that information.

Another strange thing is that two of our websites are running on this RDS instance, and that only one was impacted by the problem.

So my question is:

What steps should I take to identify more precisely the problem?

Thank you all for your tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was a DNS issue in AWS services in the region eu-west-1. You can check that in AWS Personal Health Dashboard https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/phd

Also, It was announced later here: http://status.aws.amazon.com/#EU_block.
Now, The issue has been resolved and the service is operating normally.